# Error compilación ionic mips64el-linux-android

Tags: angular, ionic, cordova

Estoy recibiendo este error por consola al lanzar la aplicación de ionic al movil. Hasta ahora no me lo lanzaba este error y he depurado sin problemas, pero de repente me sale este error en la consola :

> No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: mips64el-linux-android

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':CordovaLib'.

  > No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: mips64el-linux-android
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

¿Qué puede estar pasando? Ayuda!!!
Pongo la imagen de la consola por aquí tambien:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]